# Symfony3 You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine". MongoDB FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony

I'm having a problem with Symfony3 and FOSUserBundle with MongoDB. When I run the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get this error:

> You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine".

I followed exactly the Tutorials on Symfony Website. What does the error mean?

TY.

Comment: It's means that you followed tutorial for MySQL instead of MongoDB.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem at all?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it indeed is a MongoDB problem like @malcolm indicated, you probably need to read through this:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be of a help to Your problem, if defined in services.yml file.:

```
services:
    fos_user.doctrine_registry:
        alias: doctrine
```

Or

```
services:
    fos_user.doctrine_registry:
        alias: doctrine_mongodb
```